# Decomposition of tensor field on hypersurface

Tags: limits, differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, tensors

Lets consider the following situation: $(\mathcal{M},g)$ is a Lorentzian manifold, which is globally of the form $\mathcal{M}\cong I\times\Sigma$, where $I\subset\mathbb{R}$ and $\Sigma$ is some $3$-dimensional hypersurface. Furthermore, let $T$ be an arbitrary symmetric $2$-tensor field on $\mathcal{M}$. Then, in some coordinates, I can decompose

$$T_{\mu\nu}\mathrm{d}x^{\mu}\otimes\mathrm{d}x^{\nu}=T_{00}\mathrm{d}x^{0}\otimes\mathrm{d}x^{0}+2T_{i0}\mathrm{d}x^{0}\otimes\mathrm{d}x^{i}+T_{ij}\mathrm{d}x^{i}\otimes\mathrm{d}x^{j}.$$

This essentially provides a decompisition of the form (in the sense of $C^{\infty}(\mathcal{M})$-module isomorphisms)

$$\Gamma^{\infty}(T^{\ast}\mathcal{M}^{\otimes_{s}2})\cong C^{\infty}(\mathcal{M})\oplus\Gamma^{\infty}(\mathcal{M},T^{\ast}\Sigma)\oplus\Gamma^{\infty}(\mathcal{M},T^{\ast}\Sigma^{\otimes_{s}2})$$

where $T_{00}$ is interpreted as a function in $C^{\infty}(\mathcal{M})$, $T_{i0}$ of beeing the components in coordinates of an element in $\Gamma^{\infty}(\mathcal{M},T^{\ast}\Sigma)$ and similarely for $T_{ij}$.

Now, is it possible to establish isomorphisms

$$C^{\infty}(\mathcal{M})\cong C^{\infty}(I,C^{\infty}(\Sigma))$$
$$\Gamma^{\infty}(\mathcal{M},T^{\ast}\Sigma)\cong C^{\infty}(I,\Gamma^{\infty}(T^{\ast}\Sigma))$$
$$\Gamma^{\infty}(\mathcal{M},T^{\ast}\Sigma^{\otimes_{s}2})\cong C^{\infty}(I,\Gamma^{\infty}(T^{\ast}\Sigma^{\otimes_{s}2}))$$

i.e. to interpret $T_{00}$, $T_{i0}$ and $T_{ij}$ as "smooth time-dependent functions, co-vector and tensor fields", respectively? What I mean with smooth in the notation above is the following: If $X:I\to\Gamma^{\infty}(T^{\ast}\Sigma)$ is a map, for example, then $X_{p}(t)\in T_{p}^{\ast}\Sigma$ for all $p\in\mathcal{M}$, $t\in I$, and hence, it makes sense to define derivative with respect to $t$ in the usual way, i.e.

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}X_{p}(t)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{X_{p}(t+h)-X_{p}(t)}{h}$$

where we choose an arbitrary norm on $T_{p}^{\ast}\Sigma$, for example, the one induced by the metric $g$ (the choice does not matter, since on finite-dimensional spaces they are all equivalent). Similarely, the spaces are defined for the other two cases.